# In Magento 2.4.1 auto stop sending invoice email after complete payment without admin option

Tags: magento2.4

I want to stop auto invoice email after complete payment, In admin, there is already an option to stop invoice mail but if I disable that option in admin then when I send an invoice by programmatically it does not work.

Does anyone have to know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: just a thought, if you are sending invoice email programmatically, why dont you set that system config value to enable email temporarily and disable that again once our code sends out email

Comment: can you add a code for sending programmatically invoice ??

Comment: Hi @NileshPlus91 am sending invoice email by $invoiceSender->send($invoice) this code work when we enable invoice setting in admin. I duplidate send function and there I hard codded $invoice->setSendEmail(1) still email does not go if admin invoice is disabled

Comment: with the help of this article: https://meetanshi.com/blog/programmatically-set-magento-2-core-config-data/ you can change configuration value before sending invoice.